# Iterate through directory until a specific folder name is found

Tags: python, loops, search, directory

I'd like to walk several layers down through a directory, until a folder named with an integer is found, then do certain operations on stuff inside the folder. It's important that I can still access the name of the processed folder (the integer) since I use that for naming the output of the operations. The folders I need will always have a single integer in the name, no other characters.
I've tried a nested loop which works, but unfortunately I don't always have the same depth (sometimes it goes 2 folders down, sometimes more)

This is what I've got so far and it seems to work on some directories, but returns nothing on others.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("directory"):
    for name in dirs:
        try:
            int(name.split("\\")[-1])
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
        except:
            continue
```

What would possibly work even better is that the loop stops as soon as it reaches a folder that contains folders with integer names then does certain operations on these integer-sub folders.

What would be the most efficient way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. I only made small changes to make it a little more generic. Let me know what is not working, such as the paths of directories that are missed, and I'll improve my answer.

```
import os

def process_folders(root_dn, f, op):
    processed = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dn):
        for dn in dirs:
            if f(dn):
                path = os.path.join(root, dn)
                rv = op(dn, path)
                processed += [(dn, path, rv)]

    return processed

# This is the function that tests if the directory name is one you're looking for
def dn_filter(s):
    rv = True
    try:
        int(s)
    except:
        rv = False
    return rv
    # -or-
    #return s in in ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

# This is the function that will process your directory. Return a value to indicate success
def dn_op(dn, path):
    print('Processing:', dn, 'at', path)
    return True

root_dn = '.'
processed = process_folders(root_dn, dn_filter, dn_op)
# Print all processed directories and their associated return values
for dn, path, success in processed:
    print(dn, path, success)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import re

def findDir(basePath):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basePath):
        print(dirs)
        for name in dirs:
            try:
                if re.match("\\d", name):
                    return (root, name)
            except:
                continue
    return ('', '')



(r,n) = findDir("G:\\Kinetochore_3C_imaging")
print(n)
print(os.path.join(r, n))
```